# Terminal Services Server autorun on windows startup with registry key entry

Tags: windows-server, terminal-services

I'm not familiar with terminal servers and I can't find this information anywhere.

I wanted to know if the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run` registry entry works on terminal servers or should I use the specific entry of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` or `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` as I'm unsure of the differences.

I was hoping someone with more experience working with terminal servers could be of assistance

Comment: are you looking to run something for a specific user, or all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run` in Terminal Server environment in the very same way you'd use it in "normal" environment. From [KB321707](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321707) (it was written for Windows 2000, but applies to modern Windows versions as well):

> You can specify a command line in the registry to start a program when
>   users log on to Terminal Services:
>
> 1. On the Terminal Services server, start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).
> 2. Locate and then click the following key in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
> 3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **String Value**.
> 4. Type any name for the value, and then click **Modify** on the **Edit** menu.
> 5. In the **Value Data** box, type the command line for the program that you want to start when users log on.
> 6. Click **OK**, and then quit Registry Editor.

See the same KB for other ways to have programs start automatically when users log on to Terminal Services.

---

Regarding those `...\Terminal Server\...` registry keys you mention in the question, they are part of so-called registry shadow. They are created by Terminal Services running in Install mode, and you do not normally need to work with them directly. Check out Nicholas Dille's [The Shadow Key Companion](http://blogs.sepago.de/d/nicholas/2012/06/21/the-shadow-key-companion) if you're interested in the topic.